# How to pass from CustomPainter to a CanvasElement to get .toDataUrl?

Tags: flutter, dart

My question is the following, from my mobile application I have a **CustomPainter** in which I draw, lines, circles, etc... When I finish drawing, I finish recording with `PictureRecorder.endRecording` to obtain the **Picture** and then the **Image**, more or less like this :

```dart
/// Stop recording
final Picture picture = canvasRec.endRecording();

Image testImage = await picture.toImage(
   width,
   height,
);

ByteData testBytes = await (testImage.toByteData(format: ImageByteFormat.png)) as ByteData;

File.writeAsBytesSync(testBytes.buffer.asUint8List());
```

So far so good, however I need to figure out how to convert that canvas and send directly to the API like `.toDataUrl`

Besides I saw that the method exists, but with the use of `html` and **CanvasElement**, but I already have my **CustomPainter** with all my logic, so I don't know how to do it.

Comment: you need to send a POST request with your data, what `toDataUrl` do you mean?